# Clash of Clans - Data usage

Tags: clash-of-clans

Can anyone advise the best Android/Google pay options and settings for Clash of Clans?

My son's previous smart phone used around 200-300mb per month. Now he uses that in a week with his Samsung Galaxy S4.

Comment: so you want to reduce the mobile internet usage for CoC? AFAIK you can block it from using mobile internet and let it use wifi only.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have Wi-Fi .  We are a bit far behind in South Africa, and data usage is expensive.

Comment: You might find some useful perspectives over on the Parenting SE site. While the answers over there won't tell you how to limit the data usage from a technical point of view, you might find some ways of teaching your son to limit his own data usage and become a more responsible individual.

Comment: i still don't get what you want. do you want to limit that data usage? or make CoC use less data (which wont be possible)?

Comment: I am happy with my son using the data, I can see that it is all on COC.  I just want to try and determine why, when he was playing on hos Samsung Trend - was his usage so low, and now so high.  He is playing less now than he used too.  (We play together in the same clan etc, so I see what he is up to)

Comment: There must be some setting that is effecting the usage.

Comment: @BubbleBoy There has been additions to the game throughout time; for example there was the Halloween specials lately that I believe must have increased the volume up/down for proper usage and those won't be removed... and another thing is perhaps that your son is playing the game more? The game kind of requires the player to be a bit more active as they progress because they have more to do to keep on progressing at a decent pace, plus players who don't progress much tend to get rejected from clans unfortunately, as they are considered burdens =/

Comment: Hi Jerry  -  he is actually playing less than before because his data is capped, so once it is used up - he must buy more.  This was happening even before the update.

Comment: @BubbleBoy Have you tried getting his previous smart phone?

Answer (score 9):

The Clash of Clans game doesn't have options to limit data usage per se.  For most users this isn't a big deal because they have wifi for when at home and cellular data plans that start at 1GB of free data so game designers would have little reason to worry about such features.

That being said, some things you could try:

- In the CoC settings there is an option to connect with Facebook.  Consider turning this off if he is connected as CoC may periodically download data from Facebook in the background.
- Avoid doing things in the game that may consume data but are unnecessary such as:

  - Playing and sharing replays of attacks
  - Conversing on global chat
  - Logging into the game just to tap on your collectors when you have a shield.  Every time you wake up the game and see that loading bar it is syncing data with the servers.  If you fire up the game just to tap on your collectors when you could wait longer to do so you are using up a little bit of extra data.
  - Similarly if you log into the game every time it sends a notification you've been attacked or an upgrade finished etc, but you don't really need to, you are use up a little extra data.
  - Searching too long for an opponent to attack.  Each time a new potential opponent loads, data is being sent/received.  If he is, for example, looking for a TH to snipe (which is a pointless activity), that's wasting data.

That all being said, all of this probably doesn't amount to much data savings.  Whenever Supercell releases an update to the game that needs to be downloaded, that involves a lot of data transfer and there was recently a Halloween update as well as the Wizard update that contained some videos that probably ate up a lot of data.

You might also want to confirm the data usage is coming from CoC.  I play the game more then I should and looking at my cellular data stats CoC only used 94 MB while Facebook took in 1.2 GB.  Just make sure you aren't chasing a red herring.